# How to merge 2 php arrays?

Tags: php, laravel, algorithm

I have 2 xPath requests :

```
$medias = $xpath->query("//strong//a[contains(@class, 'no')]");
$links =  $xpath->query("//strong//a[contains(@class, 'no')]/@href");
```

My goal is to have only one array that contains something like this :

```
0 => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "A besúgó"
    "link" => "xyz"
]
```

I tried this

```
    $i=0;
    foreach($medias as $media)
    {
        $tab[]['titre'] = $media->textContent;
        $i++;
    }
    $i=0;
    
    foreach($medias as $media)
    {
        $tab[]['lien'] = $media->textContent;
        $i++;
    }
    
    
    
    dd($tab);
```

But it's ugly and it does not work. Can you help ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: @dave i don't think they are trying to do a straight merge however. i think they are trying to create more structured data out of the two arrays, with each element containing an associative array with two named elements. the question is poorly worded.

Comment: What is the use of $i here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, but from what I can tell it is this.

```
$tab = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count( $medias ); $i++ ) {
    $tab[] = [ 'titre' => $medias[$i], 'lien' => $links[$i] ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may just use array_merge() function to merging more than 1 arrays

```
array_merge(array1, array2, array3, ...)
```